# How to implement OnValueChange for any type class field in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to implement OnValueChanged method which will called automaticaly when target field will be changed. For example I Have a MonoBehaviour class in unity and if it's enum field value is changed then execute some code. Here is the pseudocode

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour {

   public enum SomeEnum { Value1, Value2 }

   public SomeEnum MyEnum;

   void Update() {
       if(MyEnum value isChanged){
           call OnMyEnumChanged();
       }    
   }

   public void OnMyEnumChanged() {

   }

}
```

Hope my question is clear, any suggestions is highly appreciated

Comment: put a getter and setter on the field, and on setting, call a deligate for onenumchanged

Comment: I tried that but it does not work, because when I am changing the value from unity editor value change is not detecting

Comment: If you are using this script in editor consider using `ExecuteInEditMode` attribute. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html

Comment: No, no. This is not what I want

Comment: @UnityDev define `if it's enum field value is changed` .. you mean by code or via the Inspector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking up some information on google I found OnValidate method which is called when something is changed from editor/inspector. This is code which i wrote to handle value change from editor

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum SomeEnum { Value1, Value2 }

    public SomeEnum SomeEnumProperty {
        get => myEnum;
        set {
            if (myEnumObserver == value)
                return;
            myEnum = value;
            myEnumObserver = myEnum;
            OnMyEnumChanged();
        } 
    }

    [SerializeField]
    private SomeEnum myEnum;
    private SomeEnum myEnumObserver;

    void OnValidate() {
        if (SomeEnumProperty != myEnumObserver) {
            SomeEnumProperty = myEnum;
        }
    }

    void Update() {

    }

    public void OnMyEnumChanged() {
       Debug.Log("ValueChanged Called");
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to swap the order of these lines: `myEnum = value;` `myEnumObserver = myEnum;`

Comment: You should also remove the now empty `Update` method entirely! Unity calls it anyway as soon as it exists which is only wasting resources. Also `OnValidate` is only called in UnityEditor .. not in a built game

Answer (score 1):

Normally we would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but I don't know how far that goes in Mono/Unity.

For what it's worth:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour, INotifyPropertyChanged {

   public enum SomeEnum { Value1, Value2 }

   SomeEnum myEnum
   public SomeEnum MyEnum
   {
       get { return myEnum; }
       set
       {
           if (myEnum == value)
               return;

           myEnum = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("MyEnum");
       }
   }

   void Update() {

   }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should also remove the now empty `Update` method entirely! Unity calls it anyway as soon as it exists which is only wasting resources

Comment: @UnityDev what exactly is your case?

Comment: My case was that I wanted to call some method when my custom enum value would have changed, I done that, thanks for ur help

Comment: @derHugo I have my doubts that Unity will call a private method. This was just for illustration purposes, the fact that I removed code from `Update()`, which is why I left it.

Comment: @rfmodulator and how do you think any of [`private void Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html), [`private void Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) etc are called? Unity invokes them as messages if they exist ;) It doesn't matter whether they are `private` or not. In this case at least comment it out ;)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks. That makes sense, and explains why I have seen a lot of code with a private `Update()` method. I'm not a Unity developer by any stretch of the imagination.